# Put in double quotes all between two patterns in every line

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have ndjson file, with strings like this:

```
{"created": "2016-03-08 00:00:00 UTC", "changed": "2016-03-08 08:51:56 UTC", "rev": 28990, "status": 1, "user": [{"user_id": null, "name": null, "loyaltyCard": 123456789012}], "id": "26680533564", "tax": null, "products": [{"price": 289, "quantity": 1, "coupon": null, "id": "4122"}],  "shipping": 0.0}
```

I need to take in double quotes values of "loyaltyCard", considering, that it could be digits, letters (cyrillic also) and anything else.

Expecting to see something like:

```
UTC", "rev": 280, "status": 1, "user": [{"user_id": null, "name": null, "loyaltyCard": "123456789012"}], "id": "26680533564", "tax": null, "products": [{"price": 289, "quantity": 1, "coupon": null, "id": "4122"}],  "shipping": 0.0}
UTC", "rev": 56990, "status": 1, "user": [{"user_id": 543445, "name": null, "loyaltyCard": "1233bla456bla"}], "id": "5454580534", "tax": null, "products": [{"price": 869, "quantity": 2, "coupon": null, "id": "86854"}],  "shipping": 0.0}
```

Comment: Please add your expected output from the given input.

Comment: Use `jq` for parsing JSON data

Comment: @anubhava all I know about JQ is that it's named JQ :(

Comment: If it is valid JSON, the value of `loyaltyCard` should already be quoted if necessary.

Comment: @chepner nope, it's not a valid json, and I can't do anything with that :(

Comment: You're trying to fix this in the wrong place, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wrap up loyaltyCard value in double quotes, you can use a regex like this:

```
(loyaltyCard": )([^}]*)\}
```

With a replacement string:

```
\1"\2"}
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gJ8yT4/3)**

**Update** for Vim: to find/replace in vim you can use:

```
:%s/\(loyaltyCard": \)\([^}]*\)\}/\1"\2"}/
 ^ ^----------------------------^ ^-----^
 | + Pattern1 (w/capture groups)  + Pattern 2 (w/ group refs)
 + substitute cmd
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, mate. Please, tell me, how can I transform it to use in vim? (if I can)

Comment: U're goddamn lifesaver, mate, thank you for your prompt reply, I've just thought I'll lose my mind f**ng around this

Answer (score 0):

```
s/: (\d+)/: "$1"/ might do the trick
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way:

```
 m/"loyaltyCard"\:\s*"([^"]*)"/g;
```

If you want to give a escape sequence for quotes your wish.